# Plot 3d with y as point, x and z as vectors in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot 3D figure in R where I have y has fixed point and x and z are vectors. For example:

```
x=[1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
y=0
z=[100,200,300,400,500,600,700]

x=[1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
y=1
z=[...] // 7 points
```

and so on till y = 10

I tried to use `wireframe` where y = 1, and I always have error like that:

```
Error in eval(substitute(groups), data, environment(formula)) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

Can anyone helps me to get that data plotted?

Comment: You should have gotten an error when you set up x and z, too.       `x = c(1, 2, 4, ...)`.  Same with z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` must equal 1 for all values of `x` and `z` to plot in 3D. And it must be in `matrix` form.

```
> x <- c(1,2,4,8,16,32,64)
> y <- rep(1, 7)
> z <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700)
> d <- matrix(c(x, y, z), 7, 3)
> d
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    1  100
## [2,]    2    1  200
## [3,]    4    1  300
## [4,]    8    1  400
## [5,]   16    1  500
## [6,]   32    1  600
## [7,]   64    1  700

> library(lattice)
> wireframe(d, scales = list(arrows = FALSE),
            drape = TRUE, colorkey = TRUE,
            screen = list(z = 30, x = -60))
```

[image]